# How to pull reviews dynamically for multiple Facebook pages using the same App?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, plugins

I'm trying to build a WordPress plugin that let users to pull their reviews from FB pages. I have already submitted and got my FB approved for 'manage_pages' permission.

Now, whenever a user connects his FB with our app an access token is generated to pull reviews.

The issue is that whenever a new access token is generated for a page, all the previously generated access tokens don't work anymore and I'm getting this error message when I debug them using FB Access Token Debugger Tool:
"The manage_pages permission must be granted before impersonating user's page"

The error above only appears when a new token for another page is generated. Any advice ?

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FUxt.jpg)

Comment: _“The error above only appears when a new token for another page is generated.”_ - for the same Facebook user? Or a completely different one? You are storing one token per user, right?

Comment: Yeah, one token is stored for each user. For more clarification, If I connected FB page #1 to my app, I get the access token valid, then If I tried to connect FB page #2 to my app, I get the error above for page #1 access token

Comment: Different users, or same one?

Comment: Actually, I'm using the same user, but different pages